# Manipulating subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a structure where I need to add or subtract a specific value from a subdocument array, however when I use `$set` all the other properties gets removed if I do not explicitly set a value for them. How can I query the subdocument I need and edit the property value leaving the other objects & properties intact?
example

```
{
   title: 'james',
   subby:[{id:1323313,total:10,name:'test'}, 
          {id:2222222,total:10,name:'test2'}
         ]
}
```

In this example I would like to subtract 1 from the total of the subdocument with the name 'test'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to find an array element with `name: test` and then use [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/index.html) to subtract `1`. Try:

```
db.col.update({ title: "james", "subby.name": "test" }, { $inc: { "subby.$.total": -1 } })
```

You can also use the [all positional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/index.html) operator to modify all subdocuments (MongoDB 3.6+):

```
db.col.update({ title: "james"}, { $inc: { "subby.$[].total": -1 } })
```

and the [filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html) to modify selected subdocuments (MongoDB 3.6+):

```
db.col.update({ title: "james" }, { $inc: { "subby.$[cond1].total": -1, "subby.$[cond2].total": -1 } }, { arrayFilters: [ { "cond1.name": "test" }, { "cond2.name": "test2" } ] })
```

Comment: Thanks for this, pointing me in the right direction. Working with sub documents can be a bit tricky. Would this work for an array of items? like suppose I wanted to increment both sub documents by different amounts, Would it work for such a case?

Comment: @kabuto178 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/ for multiple sub-docs

Comment: @kabuto178 modified my answer

Comment: @mickl that is exactly what i was looking for, thanks for the direction